# Want to get specific document fields from multiple documents in flutter cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, fluttermap

[this image have the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvayY.png)

I wanted to grab the latitude and longitude of all documents and display it in flutter map (leaflet).

```
FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        center: latLng.LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
        zoom: 13.0,
      ),
      layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
        MarkerLayerOptions(
          markers: [
            Marker(
              width: 80.0,
              height: 80.0,
              point: latLng.LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
              builder: (ctx) => Container(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.circle,
                  size: 30,
                  color: dc,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I put line 15 just for sample, i wanted to access all the user's lat long . please help, and thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to fetch all the documents and then parse that field the array of documents you receive

Comment: what if i don't have the document id for all, but have to access all

Comment: You can get all the documents in the collection by `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').get()`

Comment: yeah now i got how to get data , but how to put all those lat long in leaflet map, kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, you have to get the documents for your `shopkeepers`.
- Then, iterate over those documents, and extract your lat and lng values, and add them to a list.

```
Future<List<LatLng>> getCordsFromFirebase() async {
List<LatLng> coordinatesList=[];
var results = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('shopkeepers').get();

for (DocumentSnapshot item in results.docs){
coordinatesList.add(LatLng(item.data()['latitidue'], item.data()['longitude]));
 }
print('Length of cords list is: ' + coordinatesList.length.toString());//
return coordinatesList;
}
```